# How to open R graphic window in linux.?

Tags: linux, r

When running an R script in Windows, the command windows() opens an annex windows to plot the graphs. This is very handy when running simulations with several time steps.

But I moved to Linux and I want to do the same when running from then terminal with the command Rscript. I tried replacing windows() with dev.new() but the only results is a pdf with the series of graphs. I just want to see the graph, but not store it.

Is there another approach?

Comment: I see your point.  Alternatively, you could just do everything in the cloud, http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/ (but I would like to see the answer to your question).

Comment: @user1945827 Precisely, I want to skip using Rstudio. Some of the computers haven't this program installed.

Comment: `dev.new()` fires up a graphic device according to `getOption("device")` which in my case produces a graphics window (I'm on Linux).  How is yours configured to produce a PDF? Are you calling a server and you don't have an X11 graphics display?

Comment: Please read `?Devices` and `?x11`, if you have display capabilities.

Comment: @Spacedman I'm not that skilled in R or Linux and I don't understand exactly what you mean by calling a server. What I get everytime I run the script is a message like this "dev.new(): using pdf(file="Rplots.pdf")"

Comment: I changed the windows() to x11() and now I'm getting the graphic window. The problem now is that the graph is out the margin of the window... is there a method to adjust the graph?

Comment: You need to increase the size of the `x11()` device. See `?x11`.

Answer (score 1):

As comments also mentioned, you can use

```
 X11(display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg, canvas, fonts, family, xpos, ypos, title, type, antialias)
```

for example following would lead to a 10x10 inches square plot

```
 X11(width=10, height=10)
```